# How to get a list of radio button in a form for an entity which have one-to-many many-to-one relation?

Tags: forms, symfony

Actually I have a Project entity with a one-to-many relation on ProjectsWorkgroups entity which have a many-to-one relation on Workgroup entity. I would like to display many radio buttons and to be able to assign a Workgroup to the project.

I try that, without success

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name');
    $builder->add('color');
    $builder->add('workgroups', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Workgroup',
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => true
    ));
}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a radio buttons you must change property multiple to false and expanded to true
like this:

```
$builder->add('workgroups', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Workgroup',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => true
 ));
```

for more details:
[Select tag, Checkboxes or Radio Buttons](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: I add the expanded option, the template is returned but when I persist the project entity, no records are created in the middle table (projectworkgroup). Should I need to create a form type based on the ProjectWorkgroup entity?